# Cmake add_definition to compute absolute path of a file

Tags: cmake

I have a project where compilation and test running is managed by cmake. The test involves reading a special test file, which is located in different directory from the test file and would need an absolute path. I define the path to the testfile in my tests.cpp like this:

```
#define ARPA_TESTFILEPATH "/path/to/project/root/arpa/toy_lm.arpa"
```

I want to pass that define via cmake so that other people can checkout the project and run the tests without modifying anything. I know I can add defines in cmake via:

```
add_definitions(-DARPA_TESTFILE="/path/to/project/root/arpa/toy_lm.arpa")
```

However how can I add a variable to the define so that it automatically resolves the path? I am looking for something like:

```
add_definitions(-DARPA_TESTFILE="$(PROJECTROOT)/arpa/toy_lm.arpa")
```

Is that possible?

EDIT:

Basically say the project is checked out in a directory

> /home/pesho/project
>   the project directory contains CMakeLists.txt. How could I get the absolute path to the projects directory so that I can include it in a variable and then define it during compilation.

Comment: My experience tells me is better to use them  in config.h.in with [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html)

Comment: Basically, what you have shown will do exactly what you want. What do you mean by "project root". Is it the directory containing the top level `CMakeLists.txt` script?

Comment: @kdopen yes, this is what I mean by project root. How could I get the absolute path to that directory without executing some ugly "pwd" in command line.

Comment: `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` will give the absolute path to the directory in which `project()` was last called. See `cmake --help-variable PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the path in a CACHE variable. It make it accessible through ccmake command :

```
set(PATH_TO_ARPA "${DEFAULT_PATH_TO_ARPA}" CACHE FILEPATH "Description of the option")
```

See documentation : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html

Comment: I need an absolute path to the project. How do I get it from cmake. If I know it I can put it in a variable and put it in there.

Comment: Use `get_filename_component` from CMake. 
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_filename_component.html

Comment: Your comment solved my problem, I was looking for the get_filename_component function. Thanks.